# Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'account'

Tags: python, django, redirect, middleware, returnurl

**I am trying to redirect to login page with return url through a middleware .**

I am getting this error so can anyone answer the question why i am getting this error and how to solve this error

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def auth_middleware(get_response):
     def middleware(request):
        print("Middleware")
        return_url = request.META['PATH_INFO']
        if not request.session.get('user_id'):
            return redirect(f'account:login?return_url={return_url}')
        response = get_response(request)
        return response

    return middleware
```

Answer (score 0):

Django will make a redirect to `account:login?return_url=some_url`, but the browser does not understand this: since it sees a URL that starts with `account:`, it assumes that `account:` is the protocol.

We can reverse the view with [**`reverse(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse):

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def auth_middleware(get_response):
     def middleware(request):
        print("Middleware")
        return_url = request.META['PATH_INFO']
        if not request.session.get('user_id'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'{reverse("account:login")}?return_url={return_url}')
        response = get_response(request)
        return response

    return middleware
```

or you can make a decorator with:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from functools import wraps

def auth_decorator(view):
    @wraps(view)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Middleware")
        return_url = request.META['PATH_INFO']
        if not request.session.get('user_id'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'{reverse("account:login")}?return_url={return_url}')
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem.

But how can i use this middleware in url that has id attached to it .

'path('dashboard/pages-profile/<int:user_id>', auth_middleware(Profile.as_view()), name='profile'),'

Got this error:

**auth_middleware.<locals>.middleware() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id'**

Comment: @BibekKarna: you are using the middleware as a decorator for your views. But that does not make much sense: middleware is only given the request object, not the URL parameters.

Comment: Then how can i apply this in my view so that user that is not logged in cannot access that page.

Comment: @BibekKarna: see edit to use this as a decorator.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.It solved my problem